# Excel VBA Get Data from Closed WorkBook using Named Range

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am using the code found [here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=454) (copied below) to extract data from closed workbooks.

What I would like to achieve is using a *named range* in the target source rather than a hard-coded address. So on line 22, where it defines `Address = Cells(Row, Column).Address` I want to be able to just feed it a *namedRange* (that exists in the target) instead...but this seems to make the `getData()` function no longer work.

```
Option Explicit 

 'you can extract data from a closed file by using an
 'XLM macro. Credit for this technique goes to John
 'Walkenback > http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip82.htm

Sub GetDataDemo() 

  Dim FilePath$, Row&, Column&, Address$ 

   'change constants & FilePath below to suit
   '***************************************
  Const FileName$ = "Book1.xls" 
  Const SheetName$ = "Sheet1" 
  Const NumRows& = 10 
  Const NumColumns& = 10 
  FilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" 
   '***************************************

  DoEvents 
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
  If Dir(FilePath & FileName) = Empty Then 
      MsgBox "The file " & FileName & " was not found", , "File Doesn't Exist" 
      Exit Sub 
  End If 
  For Row = 1 To NumRows 
      For Column = 1 To NumColumns 
          Address = Cells(Row, Column).Address 
          Cells(Row, Column) = GetData(FilePath, FileName, SheetName, Address) 
          Columns.AutoFit 
      Next Column 
  Next Row 
  ActiveWindow.DisplayZeros = False 
End Sub 


Private Function GetData(Path, File, Sheet, Address) 
  Dim Data$ 
  Data = "'" & Path & "[" & File & "]" & Sheet & "'!" & _ 
  Range(Address).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1) 
  GetData = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Data) 
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I found the answer....seems I didn't Google well enough before posting, so apologies.

In the above code, in `Private Function GetData()`, replace:

```
Data = "'" & Path & "[" & File & "]" & Sheet & "'!" & _ 
       Range(Address).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
```

with:

```
Data = "'" & Path & File & "'!" & Address
```

where `Address` can be set with a *namedRange* string value...and all is well.